# Unlabeled Data - Oracle Label Security

Tags: database, oracle, security, label

If a user is granted Top Secret access to a database table, then they can READ data in that table that is TS or below, but can only write to the table at the TS level. Correct?

If the Oracle Label Security was added to the table after some data was loaded, and then there is data in the table that does not have a label assigned, would the user be able to view that data as well?

Here is a snapshot of the table:

```
 STUDENTID NAME   MAJOR          ST    AGE ADDRESS       GPA            TT
-------- ----    -----------     --    -----           ---------      ------  
   100 ABLE      HISTORY         SR     21   1 UTAH         3
  200 BAKER     ACCOUNTING       JR     19   2 IOWA         2.7
 300 CHARLES MATH                SR     22   3 MAINE        3.5
 400 DRAKE     COMPUTERSCIENCE   FR     18   4 IDAHO        2.8
 500 ELLIOT     COMPUTERSCIENCE  SM     19   5 NEVADA       3.25
 600 NED        ENGINEERING      SM     17    6 OHIO        3.55
700 TED          MUSIC           SR     21    7 OREGON      3.75
 800 FRED       ART              SM     19     8 ARIZONA    3.25
 900 RED         PSYCHOLOGY      SM     19     9 TEXAS      3.25
 920 GRANT   WAR                 SM     19     2 SOUTH      3.25        22121
 910 FUNT       DRAMA            SM     19    1 MAIN        3.25        60000
 930 IKE          HISTORY        SM     19    3 NORTH       3.25        32121
 940 FORD       FOOTBALL         SM     19    4 SOUTH       3.25        43120
 950  BUSH       POLYSC          SM     19    4 SOUTH       3.25        50000
```

14 rows selected.

The bottom 5 rows were those added after OLS was implemented, and the TT column denotes the classification label. For instance, 60000 = TS, 22121 = Unclassified (and the other labels are either sensitive or classified).

Would the user with Top Secret access be able to view the entries that do not have a TT value / label assigned? Or with OLS applied, the user can only view the data which is labeled correctly?

Hopefully this makes sense!